# Emacs indentation with sequential parenthesis in C++

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

Emacs auto indent on sequential parenthesis doesn't work fine:

```c++
int main() {
    something(int i)(
        "test", "something"
                    );
}
```

How to fix this indentation to be like normal indentation:

```c++
int main() {
  something(int i)(
      "test", "something"
  );
}
```

major mode info:

- major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
- Its value is ‘c++-mode’

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks, @pickle rick, and @0x5453,

```lisp
(c-add-style "cc-style"
         '("linux"  ;; it can be google or k&r or other c-style.
           (c-basic-offset . 2)
           (c-offsets-alist
        (arglist-close . c-lineup-close-paren))))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (c-set-style "cc-style")))
```

Comment: @phils
major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.                                                                
Its value is ‘c++-mode’                                                                   
Original value was fundamental-mode

Comment: Check the value of `'arglist-close` in `c-offsets-alist`.  Mine is set to `+cc-lineup-arglist-close`, which seems to match the behavior you are looking for.  (Though based on the description of that function, it seems like it *should* behave like your first example, so there may be more going on.)

Comment: @0x5453 would you please let me know how can I get the values of those variables?

Comment: @0x5453 it shows: `c-offsets-alist is a variable defined in ‘cc-vars.el’. Its value is nil.`

Comment: @mortezaipo You can use `C-h v c-offsets-alist` and then search for `arglist-close` manually.  Or `M-S-z (assq 'arglist-close c-offsets-alist)` to get the value directly.  Note that `c-offsets-alist` is buffer-local and is only set when you are in one of the C-based modes, so in your case you'll have to check it from a buffer that is currently in `c++-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cc-mode` is able to intelligently guess the settings you want for `c-offsets-alist` based on the indentation in the buffer.  To do this, align the code in the buffer as you want it, and evaluate <kbd>M-x</kbd>`c-guess`.

Indent the buffer, and assuming it looks OK, you can see the guessed settings with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`c-guess-view`.  Then, you could copy the entire style into your init somewhere, or cherry pick the relevant settings.

Additionally, you can get an idea of which rules apply to a given line by running <kbd>M-x</kbd>`c-show-syntactic-information` with the point positioned there.  Note, however, that this won't give all the relevant info since other rules/styles affect each others, but will tell identify `arglist-close` as the relevant rule in your example.

Comment: Thank you, when I enable `c-guess` it works fine, but when I copy the `c-guess-view` result in the emacs config, in the next restart it doesn't work again. How can I run `c-guess` in the Emacs startup? Also is it a good idea?

Comment: no, don't call `c-guess` in your init -- give the style a name and call `(c-set-style "your-style")` in your `c++-mode-hook`

Comment: @mortezaipo if you are only defining `arglist-close`, you could also consider just using `(c-set-offset 'arglist-close 'c-lineup-close-paren)` in your hook

Comment: Now, everything works fine, but my google coding style doesn't work well :D Do you know how can I override just this attribute?

Comment: did you try the code in my previous comment? that should just set the value for `arglist-close`

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I've added the solution to my question post based on your guide and help and it works fine. But it ignores the whole Google coding style. Please check my question to see the solution.

Comment: I've found it :D, I should change "linux" to "google". Now, it works perfectly!